# Stacking cubes on top of each other

Tags: unity

How can I stack cubes on top of each other? I dont want to know the code of it just how can it be done? Imaging putting cubes on top of each other in a 3d world with the cube being freely moved in all directions (like click on the cube and you can move it) I dont see how you can "raise" the cube to put it on top. Any suggestions is appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want. Could you find us an example of what you're trying to achieve please.

Comment: Could you provide a little more context on where exactly you are stuck on your problem? In general, you'll find more info on the topic of moving objects in 3D space while not allowing them to intersect under the names: physics simulation, rigid body dynamics, collision detection, or collision resolution. If these are not what you are looking for, could you elaborate a little further on your exact problem?

Comment: I recommend you first work through the Unity tutorials: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials These will teach you how to set up very basic games (which you seem to be asking about), and also give you the necessary knowledge and vocabulary to unambiguously ask about specific problems you're facing.

Comment: Oh, is this a question about how to design a **user interface for** stacking cubes? ie. if the player is interacting via a mouse/touchscreen/analog stick, they only have two degrees of freedom (left/right and up/down) but a 3D world has 3 degrees (adding forward/back). So you need some kind of intuitive control mapping or intelligent snapping in order to make up for the third dimension of input. Is that what you're asking about? If so, tell us more about how your game works, maybe include a sample screen or mock-up so we get the perspective & use cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly simple to do. From what I gathered you want to have preexisting cubes in your game and when the player clicks/taps/holds on them they move.
To make this a reality, unfortunately, you are going to have to write code and understand how colliders work.

1) Raycast a ray from the camera towards user input(finger, mouse pointer) on a distance mathf.infinite

2) If that raycast returns true, user clicked/hold his finger on a cube(I would suggest using layers here to differentiate your cubes from the rest of the objects in your scene) and you can create a fucntion that would look something like this

```
ClickedGameObject.transform.position += Input.mousePosition
```

PS. you get ClickedGameObject from raycast out in the raycast function parameters.